# Can i trigger a function with an argument from a key value pair array in php(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I don't have a lot of experience in Laravel and PHP, So the question may feel childish to you. But I am sorry, I'm really stuck here.

I am able to trigger the function 'showThis()'

Through

```
protected $listeners = array('customer-list' => 'showThis', 'payments-dash' => 'showThat');
```

But I need to trigger the function 'showThis($x)' with an argument like

```
protected $listeners = array('customer-list' => 'showThis(cl)', 'payments-dash' => 'showThis(pd)');
```

But I got an error :
Unable to call component method. Public method [showThis(cl)] not found on component: [main-body]

Please help me with this. Actually, I am trying to implement a dashboard with a sidebar. The sidebar has options to emitTo() through livewire and trigger the function to render the concerned part.

Comment: What kind of argument do you want to add exactly ? Is it a value from http request ? An object ? An object of wich class ? Would be great to know to help you

Comment: The request is a HTTP request and the argument is just a number or string, which I want to use in an if loop to do an action. The functions work perfectly without an argument in it ie. value in pair will be just 'showThis'. But if that is 'showThis()' then it throughs the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick to your first approach like so

```
protected $listeners = array('customer-list' => 'showThis', 'payments-dash' => 'showThat');
```

but for function showThis, add an argument,

```
public function showThis($someArgPassedHere) {/* code that can use passed parameter */}
```

Of course, just pass the argument in the emit as you'd normally do

```
$emit('customer-list', 12)
```

Or if you had more arguments you could pass the name => value pairs

```
$emit('customer-list', ['id' => 12, 'name' => 'someone'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Mia, But i have an argument in the function showThis($x ) and I need to use $x in loop. But again I need to assign a value as an argument using the listener.